# What happens if I don't show up to the Court (DRA, Family Court, UK)?

Tags: united-kingdom, family-law, divorce, court, legal-representation

> The matter is listed for an adjourned DRA on _____ _____ 2018 10AM. The parties to attend at 9AM.

DRA = Dispute Resolution Appointment

**I want to know what would happen if I don't show up for the Court date and don't bother to send an attorney?**

### Background story:

According to various sources, Family Court decides what is in the best interest of the children.

I've already had two Court dates:

1. Received a letter *(as if the letter couldn't be sent beforehand)* and that was it. ***(wait 3-4 months)***
2. Instructed to a £950 per session lawyer to dispute all the false statements *(I was worried I'll get too emotional)*. Court acknowledged that I do not agree but never proceeded to actually rebutting them. ***(wait 3-4 months)***

I'm considering an option of not showing up at all - saving the expense of travel, saving the expense of hiring an attorney.

In my version of reality, all the correspondence can be done via email.

So far there was absolutely nothing that had to be arranged in person.

Even the judge changed each time, no such thing as building rapport and getting to know the parties.

Of course, I am concerned that not showing up will leave an impression as if I didn't care that's why I would explain the rationale in the correspondence to the Court - I do care, I just don't feel like participating in the total bullshit legal fiction.

If the Family Law really does what is in the best interest of the children, I can put my ego aside and allow the justice... Too bad people employed in the legal system are very often poorly paid, stressed, surrounded by low vibrations and not appreciated - I don't really want to allow such people to make decisions on my behalf when I'm not present.

*(chances are that I'll either show up or pay someone, I just want to know what are the options)*

Comment: You might actually have a question buried inside the ranting. Consider removing the personal commentary and irrelevant details.

Comment: I genuinely believe that anyone with at least quarter or half brain can skip the "background story". The actual question is in the headline and then in bold: **I want to know what would happen if I don't show up for the Court date and don't bother to send an attorney?**

Comment: Anybody with at least quarter or half of a brain wouldn't have written it in the first place, knowing that it should be ignored and does nothing to help the question. The title is not the question, it's a label to help with finding the question, so adding text that doesn't add information is unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the rant and addressing the headline question: the judge can issue a warrant for your arrest for contempt of court.

Comment: I suppose that's because it's the child's court case and not the father's? As far as I know if it's a civil case you are free to stay away, except you will suffer the consequences, because you can't contradict anything your opponents claim.